# TWebbrowser carregar páginas html (forms) em sequência

Tags: html, delphi

Tenho um componente `TWebBrowser` no formulário que carrega uma página `html` (um `Form`), preenche os dados automaticamente e o envia através do comando

`WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('enviar', 0).Click;`

Após a página de resposta carregar, o programa analisa as informações da página (que é a segunda parte do formulário) e faço o mesmo comando para enviar esse segundo formulário.

Quando isolo os eventos em dois `buttons`, tudo funciona corretamente, mas ao unir os comando numa mesma sequencia, dá erro fatal.

Já tentei usar um `Sleep(4000)` depois da 1a sequencia para dar tempo de carregar a página do segundo *Form*, mas continua dando erro.

**Alguma sugestão?**

Trecho do código:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('login', 0).value := 'usuario';
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('senha', 0).value := 'senha';
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('enviar', 0).Click;

Sleep(4000);

.... Processamento dos dados ....

WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('enviar2', 0).Click;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode aplicar um procedimento de espera Real ao invés de usar o `Sleep`, ou seja, você não sabe quanto tempo o componente vai demorar para entregar o resultado, então fazemos um pulo do gato que geralmente consegue resolver e entregar no mesmo momento ou em milissegundos após!

Observe:

```
  while WebBrowser1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
    Application.ProcessMessages;
```

Enquanto o Browser estiver ocupado.... Mandamos a aplicação Processar Mensagens.

Um outro adicional à resposta, você pode explorar os eventos do componente, temos o `OnDocumentComplete` que faz praticamente a mesma coisa!

Faça os testes,

Comment: Não funcionou, continuou dando erro fatal. Mas trabalhando com o `OnDocumentComplete` e com a ajuda de um contador (o evento parece ocorrer duas vezes) consegui resolver. Obrigado.

Comment: Se usou o `OnDocumentComplete` então resolveu!